# What is meant as by an external source in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The ECMAScript language specification at section 4.4.2 which defines `implementation-deﬁned` as:

- **An implementation-deﬁned facility is deﬁned in whole or in part by an external source to this speciﬁcation**

Now what exactly is meant here by an 'external source'? Would an external source be considered some random JavaScript code put inside of some JavaScript features? Let's see with an example:

```
function func(){
     var a = 10;
     var k = "variable";
     var obj = {};
}
```

Would the external source in this case be considered the declared name, as well as the variables defined within the function?

Or if this isn't the case then could you explain what is meant by the above definition and what would be considered an external source?

Comment: Browser APIs (like `document.getElementById()`) are external to the JavaScript language.

Comment: So in that case the retrieved childNode returned from document.getElementById() would be considered as "implementation-deﬁned". Is this correct?

Comment: DOM objects are, in JavaScript language specification terms, "exotic" objects. Their behaviors are not defined by the language specification; they're defined by browsers. Similarly, there are Node APIs that are not part of the JavaScript language. Basically JavaScript code, anywhere, always exists in a context with external objects made visible by the runtime, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: @Pointy The ecma language specification says that: Exotic objects don't have "default behaviour for one or more of the essential internal methods". Now "essential internal methods" is a very ambiguous term. However, i'm suspecting that here it refers to the "internal methods" inside of ordinary objects prototype(the inherited properties from Object.prototype) ?

Comment: Things that are part of the browser are part of the browser, it's as simple as that. The JavaScript language has nothing to do with web browsers.

Comment: @Pointy Thats true but unfortunately the specifaction has quite a lot of jargon and therefor is diffucult to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *implementation-defined* refers to the implementation of the JavaScript engine and native functions provided by the host application that uses the engine. It doesn't mean JavaScript source code executed by the engine.

The term "external source" refers to documents such as the Node.js API specification or the HTML specification and related web platform standards.

Comment: So in other words:  implementation-defined means any JS features not defined by the ECMAScript language specification(e.g. Window.document)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though for that reason I wouldn't call `document` a "JS feature", I'd call it a "browser (or DOM) feature".